# Drupal website CSS stopped in all browsers

Tags: css, drupal

I maintain a website http://www.cugc.org.uk/cms/ which is built in Drupal 7.19

When I came back from holiday I discovered that all the formatting has disappeared from the website in all browsers I have checked (IE, FF, Chrome).

I believe it mas be a permissions because the code still links to the correct CSS files which I can view via FTP but I cannot view when using a browser.

Here is an example of  part of the

```
<style media="all" type="text/css">
@import url("http://www.cugc.org.uk/cms/modules/system/system.base.css?mia4dq");
@import url("http://www.cugc.org.uk/cms/modules/system/system.menus.css?mia4dq");
@import url("http://www.cugc.org.uk/cms/modules/system/system.messages.css?mia4dq");
@import url("http://www.cugc.org.uk/cms/modules/system/system.theme.css?mia4dq");
</style>
```

I've check on the server and the permissions for all these files is set to 774 i.e. world readable. but I get a 403 error when trying to access the files in browser.

Comment: Seems to be fine now. Is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now fixed, somehow the css files had been changed so they where not world readable, once the permissions had been changed problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the .htaccess file in the CSS's folder configured right. Edit the .htaccess file by deleting all lines of code in this file, but let the empty .htaccess file in the CSS's folder (In this way Drupal cannot place a new htaccess in the folder). This was working for me several times.